# Why does pressing up button in VS Code for Mac switch focus instead of taking me to the previous line

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have Googled this extensively and have got nowhere.

When I press the up button in VS Code for Mac, instead of taking me to the previous line, it sometimes, randomly, shifts focus to other areas, like the terminal, the notification symbol (bottom right), and file browser.

See screen recording attached. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GdVtBcUV48o

Comment: Run the `Developer: Toggle Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting` command to see what the upArrow is resolved to - you may have another keybinding that is taking precedence.

Comment: @Mark could you please elaborate on what this `Developer: Toggle Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting` is and how do I run it?